# Using React and Ajax to receive data

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, reactjs

I trying to get a grasp of React/ I am using Ajax to receive data, and then I want to display this data using React.  I am receiving the data, but I can't figure out how to display the titles of each entry.  What am I missing here.

```js
<!-- App.js -->
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import $ from 'jquery';
import Movies from './Components/Movies';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {

    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state = {
            movies: []
        }
    }

    getMovies() {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/76341?api_key=cfe422613b250f702980a3bbf9e90716',
            dataType: 'json',
            cache: false,
            success: function(data) {
                this.setState({ data: data.data }, function() {
                    console.log(data);
                })
            }.bind(this),
            error: function(xhr, status, err) {
                console.log(err);
            }
        })
    }

    componentWillMount(){
        this.getMovies();
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.getMovies();
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="App">
                <hr/>
                <Movies movies={this.state.movies} />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default App;


<!-- Movies.js -->
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Movie from './Movie';

class Movies extends Component {

    render() {
        let movies;
        if( this.props.movies ) {
            movies = this.props.movies.map( movie => {
                // console.log(todo);
                return (
                    <Movie key={movie.title} movie={ movie } />
                );
            });
        }
        return (
            <div className="Movie">
                <h3></h3>
                {movies}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

Movies.propTypes = {
     todos: React.PropTypes.array,
}

export default Movies;

<!-- Movie.js -->
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Movie extends Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <li className="Movie">
                <strong>{this.props.data.title}:</strong>
            </li>
        );
    }
}

Movie.propTypes = {
    todos: React.PropTypes.object,
}

export default Movie;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change `this.setState({ data: data.data }` to `this.setState({ movies: data.data }`

Comment: This still returns an empty state.

Answer (score 0):

In your ajax call, your success function is updating your component's state with the data your request receives and **assigning it to the data property of your state**.

```
this.state = {
    data: { //whatever your ajax response was }
}
```

In order to access the data you store, your component will need to reference **{this.state.data}**

**In order for your function work as intended, try assigning your response to movies instead of data**

```
this.setState({movies: data.data})
```

Comment: Are you referring to the Movie component of the Movies component?

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more clear!  I'm referencing the success function of getMovies() in your App component.  When you update your state, you're assigning your value to 'data' instead of 'movies'

Comment: I've done this and it still doesn't work.
success: function(movies) { this.setState({ movies: movies.data }, function() {...

Comment: I believe your issue is the scope of *this* inside your ajax recall.  Try adding 'var _this = this' directly above your ajax call (inside getMovies()) then call '_this.setState()' instead of 'this.setState()'

Comment: This is isn't working either.  Maybe I should try a different approach.

Comment: I made a quick CodePen that might help explain what's happening a little better.  https://codepen.io/Lance-Jernigan/pen/b95aff1c69a8f87b12761a37c5bd7949/

Answer (score 0):

I needed to change the success function from this:

```
success: function(data) {
           this.setState({ data: data.data }, function() {
                console.log(data);
            })
}.bind(this),
```

To this:

```
success: function(data) {
           this.setState({ movies: [data] }, function() {
                console.log(data);
            })
}.bind(this),
```

Data was returning an array, and I needed an object instead.  If anyone knows of a clearer/more efficient way please let me know.